# truffle - how to invoke functions based on the address elements

Tags: solidity, truffle

```
    // 1) I am invoking a function and getting the entire project list - SUCCESS

    truffle(development)> hub.then(function(instance){return instance.getProjAddr.call();})
    [ '0x5b5348b0f831da7ad1818a5b1eff5b305bd6386a',
      '0x0a4d0ae8486053bad0d9a8cd1d5cba1b73bab925' ]

    // 2) Here I am able to print the address one by one - - SUCCESS

    truffle(development)> func.then(function(result) {
     projects = result; 
     for ( var i =0 ; i < result.length ; i++)  { 
        console.log(projects[i]); 
        } 
     })


    0x5b5348b0f831da7ad1818a5b1eff5b305bd6386a
    0x0a4d0ae8486053bad0d9a8cd1d5cba1b73bab925
```

// 3) Based on this address . I am trying to invoke a function named //getProjInfo() which will return me 4 arguments. How do I achive calling it ? //- FAIL

```
    truffle(development)> func.then(function(result){
     projects = result; 
     for(var i =0 ; i < result.length ; i++) {
     projects[i].getProjInfo.call();
     }})

TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
        at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:111
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

I get the following error.

```
truffle(development)>func.then(function(result){projects = result;for(var i =0 ; i < result.length ; i++) { var sg = projects[i];Project.at(sg).then(function(instance) {return instance.getProjInfo.call();}).then(function(result) {console.log(result)});}});
undefined
truffle(development)> (node:11734) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 7): Error: Error: VM Exception while executing eth_call: invalid JUMP at 2e01c934adfa06a05d90d510117437f7727fe11b4e03f31e3936ee8ba7cf972e/6098e17865fd773133ad30d2c9bbe7071b01b7fe:138
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/vm.js:117:17
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/lib/runTx.js:59:5
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3694:9
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:359:16
    at replenish (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:876:25)
    at iterateeCallback (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:866:17)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:843:16
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3691:13
    at apply (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access and use a contract at a specific address, you can use the keyword `at` (see [Truffle documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#use-a-contract-at-a-specific-address))

Someting like this should work:

```
func.then(function(result){
     projects = result; 
     for(var i =0 ; i < result.length ; i++) {
        var projectContractAddress = projects[i];

        //I suppose the contract name is Project
        Project.at(projectContractAddress).then(function(instance) {
            return instance.getProjInfo.call();
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result)
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you !! Is it working in your environment ? I get an exception ( posted the error message to the initial question) .

Comment: That sounds like an issue in the contract code, not in web3. Could you add the solidity code of Project, especially getProjInfo().

Comment: you were right. I fixed the contract code and now things are working fine. Thank you . Have a great day